# how to display image uploaded in a submitted form with ploneformgen?

Tags: python, plone, ploneformgen

I'm using **ploneformgen**.
[edited] I'm using a **custom script adapter** from ploneformgen to create a page using the information from submitted forms. The problem is: the page generated when i submit, doesn't show the image. I would like to create a page/document with text AND one image. How can I do this?

I've tried this code:

```
#Creating the folder in zope instance. I gave the name 'conteudo' to it.
targetdir = context.conteudo

#Here asking for the form,  so we can access its contents
form = request.form

#Creating an unique ID
from DateTime import DateTime
uid= str(DateTime().millis())

# Creating a new Page (Document)
targetdir.invokeFactory('Document',id=uid, title= 'Minha Página', image= form['foto-de-perfil_file'],text='<b>Nome Completo:</b><br>'+form
['nome-completo']+'<br><br>'+'<b>Formação:</b><br>'+form
['formacao']+'<br><br>'+'<b>Áreas de Atuação:</b><br>'+form['areas-de-    atuacao']+'<br><br>'+'<b>Links:</b><br>'+form['links'])

# Set the reference for our new Page
doc = targetdir.get('uid',targetdir)

# Reindexed the Page in the site
doc.reindexObject()
```

It only shows the text, but the picture isn't there.

I tried using "setImage", but it shows an attribute error. I tried making another invokefactory but instead of 'Document', I put 'Image' then it only shows the image.

**What should I modify on my code to display *both* the text and the picture?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you imitted lot of details here.
How this coe is executed? Looking at you code *seems* you have a script adapter for PloneFormGen that is creating a `Document` content type, and this document has also a not-standard image field (you used `collective.contentleadimage` or what?).
Please confirm those details or try go give us more informations about your env.

Comment: update-> edited

Comment: At a glance, I'd think you'd need a Document extended with an image-field. For Plone-4 there's an add-on 'collective'contentleadimage' with which you can extend any existing content-type with an image-field. In Plone-5 there's a behaviour giving you this possibility.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering... and sorry for my ignorance, but how can I use it now to display the image on the document generated file? (I'm using Plone-4, and I just installed this add-on you mentioned...also tried some things already, but it didn't work). Thank you!!

Comment: @C.E.Petersson Sorry didn't notice this comment, always good to @ me, so I get notified via mail. Glad you found a solution, you can accept your own answer as the one which helped you.

Comment: @Ida Ebkes oh ok, thank you!!! and thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that worked well for me was instead of creating 'pages', I switched it for 'news items'.

Answer (score 2):

On a standard Plone Document content type does not own any image field.

If you are on Plone 4 using old ATContentTypes you must install and configure [collective.contentleadimage](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.contentleadimage).
On Plone 5 or if you are using Dexterity based contents you must add the new image field to your schema.

Comment: Ok, thanks for answering... I installed it now, because I'm using Plone 4. But, sorry about my ignorance (I'm new at plone stuff - sorry), how can I display the picture on the document now? I tried some stuff, but it didn't work. Thank you.

Comment: @C.E.Petersson image from contentleadimage is automatically shown by a viewlet. Did you configured the add-on correctly?

Comment: should I configure anything different? I did the same thing it always says to do...adding some stuff on build.cfg and then executing it. But it doesn't show the picture.

Comment: I upvoted this answer also, because in case one has a custom content-type, this would be the better answer.